# Convert $.each to plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been converting my whole website from jQuery to plain JavaScript and I am about 98% done.

The thing is that I am stuck on a seemingly easy function which I am unable to solve.

This is before

```
function searchAPI() {
    $.getJSON("get.php?q=" + searchbar_input, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $.each(value["item"], function(index_item, value_item) {
                $("#itemlist").append('<li class="items"> ... </li>');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and this is after

```
function searchAPI() {
    fetch("get.php?q=" + searchbarValue)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $.each(value["item"], function (index_item, value_item) {
                    itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... </li>';
                });
            });
        });
}
```

what should I use to replace $.each ? I cannot find an answer to a similar problem online ...

Thank you so much

Comment: you mean something like: data.forEach((index, value) => { ... }) ?

Comment: @Zac I have tried that, but it does not work ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.forEach()` is what you're looking for. 
Check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) or [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each(array, function)` translates to `array.forEach(function)`.

```
function searchAPI() {
  fetch("get.php?q=" + searchbarValue)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(function (value, index) {
        value["item"].forEach(function (value_item, index_item) {
          itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... </li>';
        });
      });
    });
}
```

The *fun* thing is the `item` and `index` arguments are reversed in jQuery, compared to JS.

---

EDIT...

Just adding a short snippet showing the above double `forEach` loop is working for an array of objects having an array under the `item` property... As mentionned in comments below my answer.

If it does not work for you, the issue is not about the `forEach` loops.

```js
let itemlist = document.querySelector("ul");

data = [
  {
    app_name: "test1",
    package_name: "com.test",
    item: ["one", "two"]
  },
  {
    app_name: "test2",
    package_name: "com.test",
    item: ["three", "four"]
  },
  {
    app_name: "test3",
    package_name: "com.test",
    item: ["five", "six"]
  }
];

data.forEach(function (value, index) {
  value.item.forEach(function (value_item, index_item) {
    itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... ' + value_item + '</li>';
  });
});
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

---

EDIT #2...

If `data` is NOT an array (but an object like below), then you need just one `.forEach()` loop...

```js
let itemlist = document.querySelector("ul");

data = {
    app_name: "test1",
    package_name: "com.test",
    item: ["one", "two"]
  }

data.item.forEach(function (value, index) {
  itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... ' + value + '</li>';
});
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

And so, your solution would be:

```
function searchAPI() {
  fetch("get.php?q=" + searchbarValue)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(function (value, index) {
        itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... </li>';  // Use value somewhere here
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought too reading the Moz documentation, but it doesn't work in any configuration I tried (swapping index and value, adding another array etc)

Comment: Post a sample of the `data`...

Comment: Sure this is what console.log(data) gives me

`com.test: {app_name: "test", package_name: "com.test", item: Array(1)}`

Comment: So `data` is ONE object or an array of objects like this?

Comment: `data` is an array and `forEach` of their `item` value it creates an HTML li

Comment: I added a snippet showing the `forEach` loops are working. Your issue maybe somewhere else.

Comment: I just found out that console gave me an error telling me `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function` and this is surely why it does not work. Do you have an idea where this could come from ?

Comment: `.forEach()` works on an array. So maybe `data` isn't... See Edit #2.

Answer (score 0):

**forEach**

You can use `forEach` but be careful, the argument order of the callback changes -

```js
function searchAPI() {
    fetch("get.php?q=" + searchbarValue)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(function (value, index) {
                value.item.forEach(function (value_item, index_item) {
                    itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... </li>';
                });
            });
        });
}
```

**improve**

But you can probably improve it -

```js
const getJSON = async url =>
  fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

async function searchAPI(query)
{ const data =
    await getJSON("get.php?q=" + query)
     
  for (const value of data)
    for (const item of value)
       itemlist.innerHTML += '<li class="items"> ... </li>';
}
```

**untangle**

But see how `itemlist` is tangled up in your `searchAPI` function? We can do better yet -

```js
const getJSON = async url =>
  fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

async function* searchAPI(query)
{ for (const value of await getJSON("get.php?q=" + query))
    for (const item of value)
       yield item                  // <-
}

for await (const item of searchApi("myQuery"))
  itemlist.innerHTML += `<li class="items">${item.name}</li>`
```

**dom api**

There's a reason we have a DOM API, so maybe we should avoid building HTML using strings. And probably best to attach this code to an event listener too -

```js
const getJSON = async url =>
  fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

async function* searchAPI(query)
{ for (const value of await getJSON("get.php?q=" + query))
    for (const item of value)
       yield item
}

function listItem (text)
{ const e = document.createElement("li")
  e.className = "items"
  e.textContent = text
  return e
}

async function onSearch (event)
{ for await (const item of searchApi("myQuery"))
    itemlist.appendChild(listItem(item.name))   // <-
}

someForm.addEventListener("submit", onSearch)   // <-
```

**demo**

Here's a demo that ties all of our ideas together in a snippet you can run and verify in your own browser -

```js
async function getJSON ()
{ await sleep(2000)   // sample delay for demo
  return [            // sample data for demo
    { item: [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}] },
    { item: [{name: "cat"}, {name: "dog"}] },
    { item: [{name: "pea"}, {name: "yam"}] }
  ]
}

async function* searchAPI (query)
{ for (const value of await getJSON(query))
    for (const item of value.item)
      yield item
}

async function onSearch (event)
{ for await (const item of searchAPI())
    itemlist.appendChild(listItem(item.name))
}

function listItem (text)
{ const e = document.createElement("li")
  e.textContent = text
  return e
}

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const itemlist = document.querySelector("ul")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", onSearch)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>

<button>search</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete reply, I will be looking into it in a short while

Comment: @cmw you're welcome. if you have any questions let me know :D